QNX Copy SCP via RZ command
i wanna copy files via winscp to an QNX system. Problem is the System doesnt has scp script.
So i wanted to copy the scp script via RZ command and Xhell / SSH. The Copy process works flawless. But i cant get the System do safe the file permanent. After every reboot it is gone. Tried Chmod commands. I have to admit i know very little about Linux command. So probaly it is an easy fix :)
After i reboot the system scp script is gone again. Any ideas?

Navigate to the directory where you want to save the scp script.
Use the chmod command to give the script executable permissions. For example, to give all users execute permission:
Bash
chmod +x scp_script.sh

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
